Factor level order in stacked bar plot chart (seaborn.objects +matplotlib)
I have a pandas dataframe. My goal is to create a stacked bar plot chart that is facetted and annotated with the respective percentages.
I am using  Python 3.12.3,  pandas version '2.2.2', seaborn version '0.13.2'
My df: counts2_melted_df 
      strain storage Predicted Class      %
0  ATCC11559    4 °C         resting  25.57
1  ATCC11559   fresh         resting  12.19
2  ATCC11559  frozen         resting  99.87
3        CD2    4 °C         resting   2.95
4        CD2   fresh         resting   2.47 

I am preparing the df so that the variables storage  and Predicted Class are catgorical and ordered. Then I plot and annotate the bar chart segments.
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn.objects as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

counts2_melted_df['Predicted Class'] = pd.Categorical(counts2_melted_df['Predicted Class'], categories=class_order, ordered=True)
counts2_melted_df['storage'] = pd.Categorical(counts2_melted_df['storage'], categories=["frozen", "4 °C", "fresh"], ordered=True)



# Color mapping
color_mapping = {
    'resting': 'yellow',
    'swollen': 'blue',
    'germling': 'red',
    'hyphae': 'cyan'
}

# Create a color palette using the color mapping
color_palette = [color_mapping[class_name] for class_name in class_order]



# Create the Plot object
plot = so.Plot(counts2_melted_df, x="storage", y="%", color="Predicted Class")

# Facet the plot by 'strain' with an increased height for each row
plot = plot.facet(row="strain").layout(size=(5,15)) # Adjust the scale factor for height

# Add the bar and stack
plot = plot.add(so.Bar(), so.Stack()).scale(color=color_palette)


# Show and save the plot
plot.show()



# Add annotations for each bar segment using Matplotlib
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(counts2_melted_df['strain'].unique()), figsize=(10, 15), sharex=True, sharey=True)

# Iterate over each facet
for ax, (strain, group) in zip(axes, counts2_melted_df.groupby('strain')):
    bottom = pd.Series([0] * len(group['storage'].unique()), index=group['storage'].cat.categories)
    for class_name in class_order:
        subset = group[group['Predicted Class'] == class_name]
        heights = subset['%'].values
        for i, (storage, height) in enumerate(zip(subset['storage'], heights)):
            ax.bar(storage, height, bottom=bottom[storage], color=color_mapping[class_name])
            ax.text(i, bottom[storage] + height / 2, f'{height:.2f}', ha='center', va='center')
            bottom[storage] += height
    ax.set_title(strain)
    ax.set_xlabel('Storage')
    ax.set_ylabel('Percentage (%)')
# Create custom legend
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=color_mapping[class_name], label=class_name) for class_name in class_order]
fig.legend(handles=legend_elements, title='Predicted Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

# Adjust layout and show plot
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

When only plotting the seaborn part, the order of storage is correct:

When adding the annotations with matplotlib, the order changes of storage 
I appreciate any help!

EDIT:
as suggested in the comments, I used so.Text. It gave me the kept the order but the text labels do not align with the correct bar segments. Any suggestion?
2nd EDIT:
I tried all the arguments for valign= ad documented on https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/properties.html but still did get no satisfactory output. Also, I am facing the problem that it makes the small values unreadable.
# Create the Plot object
plot = so.Plot(counts2_melted_df, x="storage", y="%", color="Predicted Class", text="%")

# Facet the plot by 'strain' with an increased height for each row
plot = plot.facet(row="strain").layout(size=(5,15)) # Adjust the scale factor for height

# Add the bar and stack
plot = plot.add(so.Bar(), so.Stack()).scale(color=color_palette).add(so.Text(color="w"))


# Show and save the plot
plot.show()



Why not use so.Text to add the labels, instead of re-plotting everything with matplotlib? ... though, the center alignment may be tricky.

About the ordering: enumerate(zip(subset['storage'], heights)) uses the original order of the dataframe. You could sort counts2_melted_df by 'storage' to get everything in the same order.  (I agree with BigBen's remark that plotting the bars once with Seaborn and then again with matplotlib is a bit strange)

@JohanC but shouldn't the hierarchy of the factor levels be relevant when ordering them with ```counts2_melted_df['storage'] = pd.Categorical(counts2_melted_df['storage'], categories=["frozen", "4 °C", "fresh"], ordered=True)


Indeed, the categorical order determines Seaborn's factor plot. But it doesn't change the order of subset['storage'].  subset['storage']is just a subset of the dataframe, maintaining the order of the original rows.
